# Syntax error in FROM close?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, syntax

Trying to work on this for a while now, I've gone back and fort on having my own log in page without using the tool of log in, but I prefer on using the Login just because I've used it before.
Anyways I'm getting the error when trying to log in

> Syntax error in FROM clause
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in
>   FROM clause.

Source Error:

is supposedly the `sqlDA.fill(ds.userinfo)`;

Here's the code in my class

```
public class clsDataLayer
{

   public static dsUser VerifyUser(string Database, string UserName, string UserPassword)
   {
     dsUser DS;
     OleDbConnection sqlConn;
     OleDbDataAdapter sqlDA;
     // Connects to the DB
    sqlConn=new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +"Data Source=" + 
        Database);
       sqlDA=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select AccessLevel from UserInfo"+
           "Where UserName like " + UserName+"' "+
           "and UserPassword like '"+UserPassword+"'",sqlConn);
       DS= new dsUser();
   sqlDA.Fill(DS.UserInfo);
       return DS;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sqlDA=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select AccessLevel from UserInfo"+
           " Where UserName like '" + UserName+"' "+
           " and UserPassword like '"+UserPassword+"'",sqlConn);
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the quick reply!  but what's the difference between that code and the one I provided? I did copy and paste what you posted but no luck  :(

Comment: @AlexLozano just one mistake like table name and where clause no space add so i just add one space in where clause.

Comment: Thank you ! It works! Just going to figure out now the validation of the login.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put single quote(') before variable Username, try below-

```
sqlDA=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select AccessLevel from UserInfo"+
           " Where UserName like '" + UserName+"' "+
           " and UserPassword like '"+UserPassword+"'",sqlConn);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, The difference you are looking for is the quote (') and the space while concatenating the sql string.

Answer (score 0):

Give space between `TableName userinfo` and `Where` also give spaces between other `keywords`

```
sqlDA=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select AccessLevel from UserInfo"+
       " Where UserName like '" + UserName+"' "+
       " and UserPassword like '"+UserPassword+"'",sqlConn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quote is missing from 2nd line of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all apostrophes and spaces arranged properly on `FROM` and `WHERE` clause.

```
var sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select AccessLevel from UserInfo" +
           " Where UserName like '" + UserName + "'"+
           " and UserPassword like '" + UserPassword + "'", sqlConn);
```

You can check on MS Access Query Builder if you not sure for this statement.

If you want, add `%` on `LIKE` clause to broad your search criteria.